# Incorrect response for IMAP command "UID COPY" in python's imaplib?

Tags: python, imap, imaplib

here is my goal:
1. I'm using telnet connection for copying one email from Inbox to Archive:
`. uid copy 1102 "[Gmail]/All Mail"

 . OK [COPYUID 646471928 1102 1237] (Success)`
2. The same account, copying other message to Archive:
... creating IMAP4_SLL instance, logging in, etc ...
`res = mserver.uid("copy", "1107", "[Gmail]/All Mail")

 print res`

in output i got:
`('OK', [None])`

So, who is wrong? I need new UID for message, that was just copied.
Thanks for your attention.

Comment: I recommend using the [IMAPClient](http://imapclient.freshfoo.com/) library to make your life easier :)

Answer (score 2):

This is not an incorrect response. The [IMAP standard](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501.txt) does not specify that the UID of the new message is to be returned by the COPY command. It do, however, specify that the new message shall have the date and flags preserved, so you can write some logic to find the new copy in the new folder.

Comment: thanks. So, such custom response is returning only by gmail IMAP?